# Trying to get sales receipts pulled in after hours using date diff

Tags: sql, time, datediff

I am using SQL that is provided by a 3rd party connection to a database (confusing, I know) so some features aren't available as they would be with "full" SQL. Anyway, here is what I am trying to do:

```
select     
    ,s.receiptnumber as ReceiptNumber
    ,s.salesdatetime as Date
    ,'Sales Outside of Hours' as Type 
    from vwsalesreceiptwithdetails s
     where  s.isarchived='false' 

     and GetDate() and (datepart(hh,s.SalesdateTime) >=22 OR  datepart(hh,s.SalesdateTime)<7)
```

The problem I am running into is here:

```
and GetDate() and (datepart(hh,s.SalesdateTime) >=22 OR  datepart(hh,s.SalesdateTime)<7)
```

We want to pull in sales receipts that occur between 10:05pm and 6:55am the following day because we are trying to add in a buffer of time. However, I am not sure IF or HOW this is possible within SQL. If anyone could provide some guidance I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE (CAST(s.SalesDateTime AS TIME) NOT BETWEEN '06:55' AND '22:05')
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I feel like such a fool for not knowing!